# Server Side DataTable XLS download in ASP.NET Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, csv, datatable

I changed my jQuery DataTable to a server side implementation and it works fine. Now I want to add the ability to download an XLS; similar to the built in csv export for non server side tables. I have something similar to this:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [ {
                "sExtends": "download",
                "sButtonText": "Download XLS",
                "sUrl": "/generate_xls.php"
            } ]
        }
    } );
```

Questions:

1. How do I download a file in my .NET application without having to use php?
2. How do I get all my table data for the xls or csv file? Obviously they are located on the server so it's not as straight forward as my initial front end implementation.

Feel free to provide any helpful links or pointers! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was able to figure out myself (with help from another answer). Basically I set the "sURL" to point to a controller action and then that controller created and downloaded a CSV file like this:

```
    public ActionResult AccountsExportCSV()
    {
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output);
        load_repo();
        var accounts = _repo.GetAllAccounts();

        writer.Write("Email");
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write("Full Name");
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write("Phone");
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write("Points");
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write("Date Added");
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write("Last Sync");
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write("User Type");
        writer.WriteLine();

        int userType = 0;

        foreach (Account account in accounts)
        {
            writer.Write(account.Email);
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.Write(account.FullName);
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.Write(account.Phone);
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.Write(account.Points);
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.Write(account.AddDate);
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.Write(account.LastDate);
            writer.Write(",");
            userType = Convert.ToInt32(account.UserType);
            switch (userType)
            {
                case 0:
                    writer.Write("Unknown");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    writer.Write("User");
                    break;
                case 10:
                    writer.Write("Support");
                    break;
                case 20:
                    writer.Write("Manager");
                    break;
                case 30:
                    writer.Write("Admin");
                    break;
                case 40:
                    writer.Write("Developer");
                    break;
            }
            writer.WriteLine();
        }

        writer.Flush();
        output.Position = 0;

        return File(output, "text/comma-seperated-values", "accounts.csv");
    }
```